# Set simple URL route for Area in ASP MVC, without RoutArea

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have an Area called Admin. I already have added `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` to my **RouteConfig.cs**.
I want to have such URL: `/admin` instead of `/Admin/Products/Create`
Most of the answers refer to adding **RouteArea** and **RoutePrefix**

```
[RouteArea("Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("add")]
 public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
    [Route("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create()
```

it would lead us to such URL again: `/Admin/add/Create`
Which is not what I am looking for.
I want to keep the URL simple; `/admin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `~/admin` like this

```
 [Route("~/admin")]
 public ActionResult Create()
```

so when you enter URL `/admin` it will take you to `/Admin/Products/Create`

or you can set `Route("")` to empty string which will also take you to  `/admin`

```
[RouteArea("Admin")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Create()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the second way worked properly, however the first one redirects to not found page ;)

Comment: @SharifYazdian you can accept my answer :) btw i have tested and both worked